# Argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. recevied - RepeatableContentDownloadResponse'

Tags: node.js, typescript, byte, azure-blob-storage, buffer

trying to save data received from an api, its type is application/octet-stream.

but while trying to save/convert it into other form getting error : 'The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of RepeatableContentDownloadResponse'

There is no other method present in the output to directly convert it into buffer/byte[].

Is there any method for this in Node/typescript/javascript

Comment: can you please edit question with more details and what you tried (code) ?

Comment: @Rajdeep Have you tried to stringify the object in first argument  of the buffer while converting ?

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked.

```
if (downloadResponse && downloadResponse.readableStreamBody) {
  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
  writeStream.on("finish", () => {
    Logger.logMessage(
      MessageType.INFORMATION,
      "Stream writing to file successful"
    );
  });
  writeStream.on("error", () => {
    Logger.logMessage(MessageType.ERROR, "Stream writing to file failed");
  });

  downloadResponse.readableStreamBody.pipe(writeStream);
```